# How do I test performance/load

Tags: performance, testing

Is there any way I can easily test performance/load for my Magento app other than Mage-Perftest?

Comment: if you want to get a bit more specific in looking at the Magento app itself then try profiler.

Comment: Sorry, which profiler are you talking about?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/keeping-your-magento-fit-with-built-in-profiler/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, speed/performance depends on a number of different factors, each of which can have it's own slowdowns, limitations and optimizations.

- The frontend: if you want to test the load time of specific pages of your website, you can use tests like http://www.magespeedtest.com/ or https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/
- The backend: If you want go more in depth of your code, you can use a tool like NewRelic (http://newrelic.com/), which analyzes the load for each different PHP file or model.

Comment: Thanks! I'd really like to identify which element in my code is causing the bottleneck. Is it my sql queries, the enabled modules, etc?

Comment: In that case I would recommond NewRelic, it's free for a week I think, afterwards you can still use it but features are limited (and you can get a free shirt). You just add a little bit of code on your website and that's it. You can then monitor which classes have long loading times.

But as I mentioned earlier, there are many ways to speed up Magento. Other options include caching (FPC), and simply adding more memory.

Comment: Another option would be to check the MySQL long query logs, more info here: http://www.ducea.com/2006/11/06/identifying-mysql-slow-queries/

Comment: Another comprehensive, completely free tool for monitoring general server health is [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/).

Comment: Check out XDebug http://www.xdebug.org/